# Prometheus feed one data

Tags: timestamp, point, prometheus

I feed one data, the value is `121695000128` byte, it is not a point, it is a line, keep for 9 min more.

This is the query:

```
spark_history_apps_total_input_bytes{app_id="application_1477490087146_186839"}
```

Start: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 09:55:51 GMT

End:

[image: graph1]

If i change the value from byte to MB:

```
spark_history_apps_total_input_bytes{app_id="application_1477490087146_186839"}/1024/1024
```

The result’s time is changed.

Start: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 09:55:31 GMT
End:

[image: graph2]

**Questions:**

1. Why the result's time is changed? i don't understand.
2. How can i get a point, not a line?

Please help me. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus is a time based monitoring application, collecting and processing metrics.

**Q1: Why the result's time is changed?**

The `x-axis` of you graph is time, and Prometheus is showing you the evolution of the metric `spark_history_apps_total_input_bytes` for application `application_1477490087146_186839` in time.

If you point the mouse on the last dot available in the graph, you'll have the last metric pulled by Prometheus.

**Q2: How can i get a point, not a line?**

You can't have a point in a time based graph, if you use the `Console` tab, then you can have latest result pulled by Prometheus.

Comment: I'm glad for your answer, Thank you very much. You know the line keep for 9 min more. What can i do for the line ？ How can i shorten it？